# Type of data received from SQLAlchemy database to plot chart

Tags: highcharts, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to plot a graph using highcharts in Flask. I have no problems when I give the data in the code itself. But when I retrieve the data from the database, it returns with a `,` in the end like

> [(72,),(70.5,),(78.8,),(73,),(76,),(75,),]

So, this is not passing the data to the graph and I have an empty space on the webpage.

This is the code I have used:

**views.py**

```
@control.route("/")
def index(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 350):
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height,}
    series = [{"data": [tempg()]}]
    title = {"text": 'My Title'}
    xAxis = {"title": {"text": 'xAxis Label'}}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}
    return render_template('control/index.html', uptime=GetUptime(),      chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)

    def tempg():
    tempgrs = [tempg for tempg in         Temperature.query.with_entities(Temperature.tempft).all()]
    return tempgrs
```

Is it because of the extra comma at the end, that i'm not able to get the chart or is it any other coding fault.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You get a data as string or JSON ?

Comment: The data is not JSON.